# NodeJS (Server): ReferenceError: require is not defined when type: module

Tags: node.js, server, node-modules

On Node 13.8 I'm trying to use import / export.

EG:
`import {ChatClient, Message, MessageParser} from './chat-client/module.js';`

But when i do this, I get

`SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

So in my package.json I set `"type" : "module"` but now when I try to use `const io = require('socket.io-client');`

I get `ReferenceError: require is not defined`

Is there a way to use import / export AND require?

The original error, does that just mean I have to wrap my library in a NPM library? It's a Library that's used both front end and backend so using import / export is important.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the documentation says:

```
No require, exports, module.exports, __filename, __dirname
These CommonJS variables are not available in ES modules.
```

https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_no_require_exports_module_exports_filename_dirname

You can't use both natively. If you want to do that use Babel to transpile your code.

Answer (score 7):

ES Modules in Node >= 14 do not support require.

However if you want to add it, u have to add this at the top of your file:
Everything should work fine.

```
import { createRequire } from 'module';
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);
```

Answer (score 1):

Several points:

1. Use `.mjs` instead of `.js`.
2. Never use `require`.
3. It is optional to use "type": "module".

Comment: what about __dirname is undefined

Comment: found this `import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
import { dirname } from 'path';
const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = dirname(__filename);` https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_no_require_exports_module_exports_filename_dirname

Answer (score 1):

If you use {"type":"module"} you won't be able to use ***require*** function in your project. So if you want to use **require** as well **import** you need to add the following properties in **package.json**.

```
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "stage-3",
      "latest"
    ]
  }

"babel-preset-latest": "^6.16.0"
"babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.5.0"
```